# how to override a web form submit function in drupal7?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-fapi

I have a web form with name and email fields. when the form is submitted the name and email should store in database and an PDF file should start download.

my question is how to override the submit function of the web form so that i can add that extra function after that?

Comment: look at hook_form_alter() and the submit handlers. examples here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/18641/how-do-i-alter-the-form-submission-handler

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You will need to create a custom module with [hook_form_alter](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7)() implementation.

```
function [YOUR_MODULE]_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id)
{
    if($form_id == "YOUR_FORM_ID")
    {
        // target the submit button and add a new submission callback routine to the form
        $form['#submit'][] = 'YOUR_SUBMISSION_CALLBACK_FUNCTION';
    }
}
```

The code above will execute your new callback function `YOUR_SUBMISSION_CALLBACK_FUNCTION` **AFTER** the form's default callback function.

To make your new callback function called **BEFORE** the form's default callback function, use the following code instead of the giving above:

```
array_unshift($form['#submit'], 'YOUR_SUBMISSION_CALLBACK_FUNCTION');
```

To cancel the form's default callback function and force it to use your function **ONLY**, use the code below

```
$form['#submit'] = array('YOUR_SUBMISSION_CALLBACK_FUNCTION');
```

Hope this help.

Comment: But how do we get the submission values in this submission function? I tried dpm($form) and could not find the values

Comment: Coolio found it, had to initialize the function with the parameters as &$form, &$form_state then found the values I wanted

Comment: Pay particular attention to the callback, its not within an array.